# Get top DUPLICATE results in a table (with only 1 query)

Tags: python, django

Suppose I have a model:

```python
class People(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    age = models.PositiveIntegerField()
```

And this is the current data for it:

```
name   age
Bob    18
Carly  20
Steve  20
John   20
Ted    19
Judy   17
```

How do I get the top duplicates? Hence:

```
name   age
Carly  20
Steve  20
John   20
```

I cannot find out how to do it in a **single** django query.  I can do it by sorting by age and then finding exact matches that have that top age, but that takes two queries.

Comment: So just for clarity, a sql query would be: `SELECT * FROM people WHERE age = (SELECT MAX(AGE) FROM people)` ?

Comment: And after a year or two everyone will have the exactly same age?

Comment: This is just a simple example. So...think of them as never aging (which would be great in real life...)

Answer (score 2):

Using [`QuerySet.extra`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/querysets/#extra):

```
people = People.objects.extra(where=['age=(select max(age) from app_people)'])
```

or

```
people = People.objects.extra(where=['age=(select max(age) from {})'.format(
    People._meta.db_table
)])
```

Comment: This looks to only work in SQL (from the documentation).  Is there a general way of doing it (that could conform to the supported engines)?

Comment: I can't think of a way through the ORM to avoid two queries (though there's nothing too wrong about that either)

Comment: @justderb, I confirmed that the answer code before edit only works in SQLite3. Sorry. I updated the answer. (tested in SQLite3, Postgresql).

Comment: @justderb, Not using SQL.... `from django.db.models import Max; people = People.objects.filter(age=User.objects.aggregate(m=Max('age'))['m'])`. This involves two queries (even though this is better than sorting the entire rows). Now this is only thing that come to mind.

Answer (score 1):

```
People.objects.filter(age=People.objects.order_by('-age')[0].age)
```

but its two queries clubbed into one

Comment: or `latest('age').age`